# How to filter first occurrence of each distinct element and attribute using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to keep the first distinct occurrence of a element with unique attribute value. In below sample example we can predict the distinct values, but in real time scenario it's difficult.

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?xsl-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="unique_first_occ.xsl" ?>
  <Root>
    <grade.content>
      <head.block>
        <codes.head md="hg2">
          <head.info>
            <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
            <label.designator>1</label.designator>
          </head.info>
        </codes.head>
        <codes.head  md="hg2c">
          <head.info>
            <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
          </head.info>
        </codes.head>
        <codes.head  md="hg3">
          <head.info>
            <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
            <label.designator>1</label.designator>
          </head.info>
        </codes.head>
        <codes.head md="hg3c">
          <head.info>
            <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
          </head.info>
        </codes.head>
        <codes.head md="hg3">
          <head.info>
            <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
            <label.designator>1</label.designator>
          </head.info>
        </codes.head>
        <codes.head md="hg3c">
          <head.info>
            <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
          </head.info>
        </codes.head>
      </head.block>
    </grade.content>
  </Root>
```

my xslt is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="/Root">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg1'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg1c'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg2'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg2c'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg3'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg3c'][position() > 1]" />
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xsl-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="unique_first_occ.xsl" ?>
<Root>
  <grade.content>
    <head.block>
      <codes.head md="hg2">
        <head.info>
          <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
          <label.designator>1</label.designator>
        </head.info>
      </codes.head>
      <codes.head md="hg2c">
        <head.info>
          <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
        </head.info>
      </codes.head>
      <codes.head md="hg3">
        <head.info>
          <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
          <label.designator>1</label.designator>
        </head.info>
      </codes.head>
      <codes.head md="hg3c">
        <head.info>
          <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
        </head.info>
      </codes.head>
      
      
    </head.block>
  </grade.content>
</Root>
```

the above xslt is working as expected but in real time, this hg* and hg*c (* can be any number). Is there any way to write generic code to handle this scenario instead of hardcoding like..

```
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg1'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg1c'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg2'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg2c'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg3'][position() > 1]" />
        <xsl:template match="codes.head[@md='hg3c'][position() > 1]" />
```

Thanks in advance, if any idea also really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) - e.g.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="head.block">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="codes.head" group-by="@md">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dN